# Android webview doesn't provide redirect url

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I have an android webview that goes to a certain url (xxxx/kyc/callback?id=...) and when the user clicks a button it is redirect to another url (xxxx/kyc/#/confirm). The problem is that i want to catch that url to my app but the webview never return to me that new one (xxxx/kyc/#/confirm).

I have tried to enable javascript and make use of the WebViewClient and WebChromeClient and all the functions that the 2 clients have to provide me the url but this is never happening.

```
kycWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                Timber.d("onProgressChanged " + progress + " -- " + view.getUrl());
            }
            if (progress == 100) {
                Timber.d("onProgressChanged 100 -- " + view.getUrl());
            }
        }
    });

static class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        Timber.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading -- " + url);
        if (url.contains("kyc/#/confirm")) {
            Timber.d("Bingo");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String uri = request.getUrl().toString();
        return false;
    }

    public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
        Timber.d("Updated 1 -- " + view.getUrl());
        Timber.d("Updated 2 -- " + url);
        super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Timber.d("onPageStarted -- " + url);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Timber.d("onPageFinished -- " + url);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    static class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onUrlChange(String url) {
            Timber.d("Javascript interface -- " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

and my webView

```
kycWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    kycWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    kycWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    kycWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


    WebViewClient customWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
    kycWebView.setWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
    kycWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new CustomWebViewClient.MyJavaScriptInterface(),"android");
```

Comment: first of all check your url on log so you can see the full url

Comment: @UsamaAltaf this is what i am doing with Timber. i print it in logcat

Comment: what you are getting in logs and what you are trying to do please explain

Comment: @UsamaAltaf in logs it prints .../kyc/callback?code=uhJYS14lD6nLFuxfSwcpZVOHtsjl%2BGhWc8XFr7qi&state=SS_-VUs71E5bQiIE7INNiGOJfto and after in the browser it redirects me to .../kyc/#/confirm. But in the app i see the loader (when it redirects to confirm it shows a loader) but it never prints the  .../kyc/#/confirm.

Comment: try to use `getURL()` and `getOriginalUrl()` in Timber

Comment: i actually want to read the headers of the last url that i am getting